# Is it possible to emply Jshell whithin org-babel

Tags: emacs, org-mode, jshell, org-babel

In the Jshell, we could interact with codes as:

```
jshell> 60 * 60
$1 ==> 3600
```

However, the arithmetic expression should be encapsulated in class when using org-babel.

```
#+begin_src java :classname Expression  :results output :exports both
  public class Expression {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(5 + 6);
      }
  }
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 11
```

Is it possible to use Jshell in the org-babel as:

```
#+begin_src java :classname Anonymous :session java :results output
5 + 6
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
11
```